# When making a POST request for a subdocument it comes back as undefined? mongoose, express

Tags: node.js, express, http, post, mongoose

I'm trying a to make a post request to save new data to one of my subdocuments, but I'm getting an error when trying to access the subdocument in the function. It keeps coming back as undefined. How can I get a specific user by id and create and add new data the one it's subdocuments?

model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ClassworkSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    todo: String,
    isDone: false
});

const OutcomesSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    todo: String, 
    isDone: false,
    isApproved: false
})

const MeetupSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    location: String,
    attended: false
})
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    },
    classwork:{type: [ClassworkSchema], default: []},
    outcomes: [OutcomesSchema],
    meetups: [MeetupSchema],
  });



module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

controller

```
  classworkRouter.post("/:userId/", (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.params.user_id, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return err;

    new_classwork = new classwork();
    (new_classwork.name = req.body.name),
      (new_classwork.date = req.body.date),
      (new_classwork.todo = req.body.todo),
      (new_classwork.isDone = req.body.isDone);
    console.log(new_classwork);

    user.classwork = {};
    user.classwork.name = req.body.classwork.name;
    user.classwork.todo = user.classwork.todo;

    if (user.classwork === undefined) {
      user.classwork.push(new_classwork);
    } else {
      user.classwork = [new_classwork];
    }

    user.save(function (err, data) {
      if (err) res.send(err);

      res.json({ message: "work added", data: data });
    });
  });
});
```

you can see the error in the terminal in the following phto:

[image]

Comment: It changed the error to a typeError, it is now saying "Cannot set property 'classwork' of null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this part of code

```
new_classwork = new classwork()
```

you shoud defined the new_classwrok like this :

```
let new_classwork = new classwork()
```

and `new classwork()` is not defined, you must to require Model of classwork in controller..

in schema file export schemas like this :

```
const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
const Classwork = mongoose.model('Classwork', ClassworkSchema );

module.exports = {
  User : User ,
  Classwork : Classwork 
}
```

in controller.js

```
const {User} = require('../models/certification');
const {Classwork } = require('../models/certification');
```

after require models you can use `new Crosswork` like this :

**note**: Classwork with uppercase character

```
let new_classwork = new Classwork()
```

Comment: I fixed that, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: which line is line 85?

Comment: updated my answer, you must to require classwork after that you can use new classwork()

Comment: where should i use require? I'm not familiar with using that.